# What does 'Component::__construct($config)' mean in the constructor of yii\base\Application?

Tags: constructor, yii2, components

In the constructor of [`yii\base\Application`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Application.php#L194):

```
public function __construct($config = [])
{
    Yii::$app = $this;
    static::setInstance($this);
    $this->state = self::STATE_BEGIN;
    $this->preInit($config);
    $this->registerErrorHandler($config);

    Component::__construct($config); // <====== this line confused me
}
```

I don't understand why `Component::__construct($config)` was placed at the end of the constructor.

In the [Component concept section of Yii2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-components.html), Yii recommended:

> When extending your class from yii\base\Component or yii\base\Object, it is recommended that you follow these conventions:
>
> - **If you override the constructor**, specify a $config parameter as the constructor's last parameter, and then **pass this parameter to the parent constructor**.
> - Always call the parent constructor at the end of your overriding constructor.
> - If you override the yii\base\Object::init() method, make sure you call the parent implementation of init() at the beginning of your init() method.

After reading the first two conventions above, I think at the end of the constructor of `yii\base\Application`, there would be a line such as:

```
parent::__construct($config);
```

but the last line is:

```
Component::__construct($config);
```

Does anyone could explain the line above? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm learning Yii2 now. Read documentation and code of framework. I was also stumbled upon this very moment. Fortunately I solved the mistery.

1) Yes, you are right about philosophy of framework. You should call
`parent::__construct($config);` for complete initialization of object.
But what's up about the word `parent` ?

2) `parent` is special php keyword, that means the nearest parent Class. Php can use Parent class, because it has pointer in memory where Parent class is placed, connected to Child pointer class.
Look at the picture and example of code below

[Picture - example of simple `extends`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0l4N.png)

```php
class Human
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "<br><pre>";
        print_r(__METHOD__); // show Human::__construct
        echo  "</pre><br>";
    }
}

class Man extends Human
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "<br><pre>";
        print_r(__METHOD__); // show Man::__construct
        echo  "</pre><br>";

        parent::__construct();
        /*
            I can write Human::__construct();
            It will work fine too!
            Why? - see corresponding picture
        */
    }
}

$someone = new Man();
```

So `parent::__construct();`  is the same as `Human::__construct();` because Human is the parent of Man.

3) What detailes can we see in our situation from Yii2?

`Application` extends from `Module`

`Module` extends from `ServiceLocator`

`ServiceLocator` extends from `Component`

`Component` extends from `BaseObject`

`BaseObject` implements `Configurable`

You can see this chain as `Application`->`Module`->`ServiceLocator`->`Component`->`BaseObject`->`Configurable`

4) [Look at the next picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9817Y.png)

We have powerful opportunity to choose any constructor of many 'parents', because 
php has all pointers of this classes linked together. But in our situation
framework Yii2 needs to pick up BaseObject `__construct()` method to finish 
initialization of `Yii::app` or `$this` object. We dont want to configure `Module` or
`SeviceLocator` now. So It'll be better to skip some of parent classes in hierarchy and go to `Component` class. Compare code of `Module::__construct` and parent of Component class - `BaseObject::__construct()`. It is different =)

```php
    // Module constructor
    public function __construct($id, $parent = null, $config = [])
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->module = $parent;
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    // BaseObject constructor
    public function __construct($config = [])
    {
        if (!empty($config)) {
            Yii::configure($this, $config);
        }
        $this->init();
    }
```

5) I know a lot of time has passed. But I hope, that my small investigation helps others Junior php Developers as I. Good luck!